# Why std::string.size() behaves abnormally in my code?

Tags: c++, size

Here in this code, when I'm entering inputs one by one, I'm getting correct output as expected(correct size of string using `std::string.size()`), But when I'm entering three or four inputs together(or entering input in bulk) the output (size of string) gets incremented by 2.

Ps: Look once at attached **output snippets**.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int count;
std::cin >> count;

std::cin.ignore();

while (count--)
{

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    std::cout << s.size() << '\n';
}

return (0);
}
```

[image: Output when I'm entering inputs one after another]

[image: Output when entering all input at once]

Edit: I have printed all inputted string and found that at the end, the extra characters are two blank-spaces, as you can see below, (though I tried so far, but still don't know the reason):

```
   5 
   </h1>  
   </h1>  7
   Clearly_Invalid    
   Clearly_Invalid  17
   </singlabharat>    
   </singlabharat>  17
   </5>  
   </5>  6
   <//aA>
```

Comment: Please always paste text as a text not as a picture! Now I want to copy paste input to reproduce issue and I can't do that. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438).

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ezoYKKMjh).

Comment: Except for preceding 0, all received ones are two more than expected ones. I'm just saying.

Comment: @MarekR , Okay sure, actually I'm new here (not aware of rules/ guidelines) but surely will take care of that from next time, thanks! 

Comment: Looks like you are running on Windows.  Line endings are probably `\r\n`.  The `ignore` is only ignoring the `'\r'`.  The strings being read in probably include the end-of-line.  May make a difference how the program is run, if in CMD or in an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::cin.ignore();` ignores characters to the EOF. When you enter one line, EOF is met. When you enter several lines, EOF is not met, but `\n` is met. Thus the next getline after the input 5 returns the empty string, the length is 0.

> When consuming whitespace-delimited input (e.g. int n; std::cin >> n;) any whitespace that follows, including a newline character, will be left on the input stream. Then when switching to line-oriented input, the first line retrieved with getline will be just that whitespace. In the likely case that this is unwanted behaviour, possible solutions include:
>
> - An explicit extraneous initial call to getline
> - Removing consecutive whitespace with std::cin >> std::ws
> - Ignoring all leftover characters on the line of input with cin.ignore(std::numeric_limitsstd::streamsize::max(), '\n');

The other line lengths are increased perhaps by the pasting the text containing `\r\n` that are not processed by the MS specific text file input conversions in the middle.

Comment: Is the end of a line really EOF?

Comment: In an input terminal EOF follows the end of line after pressing Enter.

Comment: that's odd. Most common command-line programs terminate when they get EOF, but not when I press enter.

Comment: This is Windows command prompt. A parody of normal terminals. Why should they terminate? cin is not tested in the code of OP.

Comment: This explains leading zero in invalid answer, but doesn't explain `+2` results.

Comment: @MarekR To explain it without an assumption I need the exact input content, in hex is better.